# Data structure for using 3 parameter/keys to find one value

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing a python script using excel and I am fairly new to programming

[Representation of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKr9J.png)

I want the use the values in column C, D and E to get the the value in column B.

I tried using a dictionary but it seems you can only use one key with a dictionary.

What data structure can I use for this situation?

Comment: The dictionary key could be a tuple of your three values.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) also applies to data.

Comment: so how was I suppose to represent the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tuple for your dictionary's key. So it would look something like this:

```
myDict = {}
myDict[(C, D, E)] = A
```